# Google "web light" feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-search

Google came up with a new feature called Google Web Light. This optimizes websites that are not mobile friendly and are heavy for users with slow connections. Sometimes even YouTube gets optimized.

They URL is like this "http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url= website url".

So, this causes some issues to websites. Mostly JavaScript issues. Take a look at these [jQuery UI elements](http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). Nothing seems to work.

Sure there is a link to view the proper website but users won't bother clicking and would leave thinking the website is broken.

How would you go around this. Is there anyway to detect if the users browser is showing the optimized website?

Here is an example of what it looks like:
[image: Google web light]

Comment: if you write proper responsive code it won't need to use Web Lite. Check google's own documentation for responsive web design (RWD)  and lookup media queries. Many websites are now based on responsive frameworks like bootstrap or Zurb's foundation

Comment: @Mousey Websites like stackoverflow and youtube also get optimized by weblight.

Comment: if you use responsive web design weblite will only be needed for very slow connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428?hl=en) explains how to opt out of WebLite:

> If you do not want your pages to be transcoded, set the HTTP header "Cache-Control: no-transform" in your page response. If Googlebot sees this header, your page will not be transcoded.

To detect WebLite instead use `$(document).ready()` in a script to detect if one of those new WebLite elements exists in the loaded DOM:

```
if (document.getElementById('lite-menu') != "null")  {
  alert("WebLite is being used") ;
}
```

If you have a fully responsite site then WebLite will only be used for slow connections

Answer (score 0):

To those of you that land on this page because you keep getting redirects using Google Web Light:

Download firefox through Raspbian Repository (or your default linux distro repository) and then seek out a browser addon to change "user agent" to desktop (just search addons for "User Agent" and you'll find something). Once done, Google will no longer terrorize you with an service they think helps you so they force it upon you.

(This may apply to others not using Raspbian such as any mobile device or small screen computer).

Comment: This answer is for the client side (Not for the website/server owner). Works great for me on Rasberry PI 4 w/ Rasbian (Raspberry has NO problem loading full web pages or any of the heavy software I've loaded such as LibreOffice)